# Replace " to ' in R for SQL query

Tags: sql, r

I'm working on an RShiny Application and the input going to RMD from App is an Array of 'Choices' depending on what the user selects. The output of Array is:

```
[1] "One" "Two" "Three"
```

I want to have the choices plugged to the SQL Query in RMD in the form:

```
('One', 'Two', 'Three')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input is:

```
x <- c("One", "Two", "Three")
```

we can can build a `WHERE IN` clause using `paste` with `collapse`:

```
sql_where <- paste0("WHERE some_col IN ('", paste(x, collapse="', '"), "')")
sql_where

[1] "WHERE some_col IN ('One', 'Two', 'Three')"
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you do not use `paste0` due to the possibility of SQL injection.

Instead, you should use `dbplyr::escape`, which escapes string inputs properly (with respect to backend implied by the supplied connection). For example:

```
dbplyr::escape(x = c("one", "two", "three"), 
           parens = T, 
           collapse = ",", 
           con = con_oracle)
```

produces the string:

```
# <SQL> ('one','two','three')
```